# Adding Favicon is causing css not to minify

Tags: css, gulp, minify, favicon, bundling-and-minification

I need to add a favicon to the application website.
It works perfectly in dev environment with non minified css.
But as soon as I move to test environment, the added app/favicon.ico is failing compression of css and henceforth breaking UI.
I am using gulp and have a gulpfile.js in project, any clue what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you are using clean-css by using gulp plugin so the plugin handles writing the files and setting a path to file. clean-css does it but when you use the binary only, see: https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/blob/master/bin/cleancss#L123

Comment: Thanks Asim. So, what is your suggestion..to use a png ..because .ico is not binary ? if you could please hint some code or usage, shall assist more, thanks